# Is there a way to know which instance was updated or created when using Realm Notifications?

Tags: ios, realm

Realm instances send out notifications to other instances on other threads every time a write transaction is committed. These notifications can be observed by registering a block:

```
// Observe Realm Notifications
self.token = [realm addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *note, RLMRealm * realm) {
    [myViewController updateUI];
}];
```

Is there a way to know which instance was updated or created when using Realm Notifications? I have workarounds but It would be much nicer if this would be possible.

Comment: No. Their documentation is pretty exhaustive, and doesn't mention that since it's already on their issue tracker. I believe it's pretty high priority.

Comment: @mazyod Thanks for answering. I saw it, they use this https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comment by [Mazyod](/users/456434/mazyod), this is indeed not available yet.
We track that as [**#601 Fine-grained notifications**](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/601). You can subscribe this issue to be updated on our further progress.